# React Native - Change text color according to background color

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to do something like as shown in the image below but I don't have any idea how to achieve that (I googled it, but I found only result for native code Swift, Obj C, ...).

[image]

Do I have to play with some layers or something like that?

Thanks for your answers!

Viktor

Answer (score 4):

Hey thank you so much for your answers,

I had to handle the text overflow with ellipsis and it was really complicated with what you proposed, so I used the maskView to do that.

I did like that:

```
// container
<View style={{flex:1, borderRadius: 200, height: 25, overflow:hidden}}>

    // Progress bar support
    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'gray'}} />

    // Progress bar, I play with "width" to indicate percentage
    <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {width: "50%", backgroundColor: 'green'}]} />
    <MaskedView
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}
        maskElement={
            // I define text which will be masked
            <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
                <Text
                    style={{marginHorizontal: 15, fontSize: 13}}
                    numberOfLines={1}>
                    Text color change
                </Text>
            </View>
        }>

        // I define a default mask that I apply to the text so that it is 'black' when it is not ON the progress bar.
        <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill,{backgroundColor: 'black'}]} />

        // I define the mask that takes the size of the progress bar and that I apply over the default mask (to overwrite it) so that the text under the mask becomes white.
        <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill,{width:"50%", backgroundColor: '#fff'}]} />
    </MaskedView>
</View>
```

So I have my default bar indicating the "maximum progress" and I define my progress bar (which grows or shrinks according to the percentage).
Then I define a MaskedView with my text as MaskedElement.
By default, I apply a black mask on the text so that it is always black no matter what happens.
And then, I overwrite this mask with the white mask which has exactly the same size as my progress bar. 
So everything under the mask of the progress bar becomes white to go on my "dark" progress bar and the rest is black!

This way, I can easily manage the text overflow with an ellpsizeMode="tail".

And this is the result:

[image: result1]

[image: result 2]

Answer (score 2):

Same styles from the previous answer but changed the implementation by adding another View that contains same text with different background color and text color inside the gray one with a position of `'absolute'`!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'Text color changes',
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.textArray);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#d0d3d6',
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
            overflow: 'hidden',
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.leftLabelStyle}>{this.state.text}</Text>
          <View
            style={{
              width: '30%',
              height: '100%',
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: '#5483b3',
            }}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='clip' 
              {styles.RightLabelStyle}>
              {this.state.text}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },

  leftLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    color: '#000',
  },
  RightLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

example at snack:https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/loading

Edit : add `ellipsizeMode='clip'` after numberOfLines to remove dots

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is a little bit different, Mainly I have 2 different views with separate styles & Finally, wrap those 2 views using the main view.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.leftViewStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.leftLabelStyle}>Text color ch</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rightViewStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.rigthLabelStyle}>ange</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 20
  },
  leftViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#5483b3",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20
  },
  rightViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#d0d3d6",
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20
  },
  leftLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    color: "#fff"
  },
  rigthLabelStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    color: "#000"
  }
});
```

This might not be the optimal solution. If you have any doubts feel free to ask.
Hope this will helps you.